# Is all mathematical knowledge stored in any volume(s)?

Tags: soft-question

Let's suppose that humanity is for some reason doomed to extinction, the planet is not going to be destroyed or anything, it's just humanity that is going extinct. For this reason, mathematical community all around the world gets together to store all mathematical knowledge up to this day, so it doesn't fade away like it never existed, and in case someone is able to find it in the future, so they can know up to what point human race was able to advance math (assuming that they could read this without any problems, this is that they could read the human language, probably English, in which this would be stored). Obviously it would have to be stored in a 100% rigorous way.

¿Is/are there any volume(s) in existence that would serve this purpose? ¿or would they have to write it?
In case such thing didn't exist for contemporary mathematics, ¿is there such thing done at least for all mathematics discovered up to a point in the past?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question. I think that for the fundamentals of math, we have pretty rigorous texts written, but for more advanced research, I think our collection of papers is all we have to bank on. I'll leave it to someone more knowledgeable than me to answer, though.

Comment: I think a guy named Bourbaki tried once, and it proved to be impractical